# How do I get rid of the 'Conversion to Swift 5 is available' warning?

Tags: swift

I'm seeing this warning message:

[image]

and when I click it I get the dialog box that allows me to select my target. I select it and I click Next to let it run. When it finishes, it tells me "No source changes necessary" so I click Update as instructed and the "Conversion to Swift 5 is available" message **does not** go away.

I've done my research and found threads that suggest changing the Swift Language Version in Build Settings to an earlier version like Swift 4 or Swift 4.2 and going through the process again. I've done this and the result is still the same.

I'm using Xcode 14.0.1

What else can I try to get this message to go away?

Comment: It can be caused by Packages / Pods used by that target. See this discussion for example: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/697832

Comment: If I recall also the workaround was updating `xcscheme` files (i.e. returned by `grep "LastUpgradeVersion" -R YourProject.xcodeproj/*`) and setting `LastUpgradeVersion` field to your current Xcode

Comment: Thanks, @khjfquantumjj. Both of my schemes are LastUpgradeVersion = "1220". When you say "setting LastUpgradeVersion field to your current Xcode", where do I change that setting?